# Both sides differentiation expression with integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integration

I have a problem with derivation of some function. This is related to computing the Poincare Map of Logistic Population model with Periodic harvesting. This function is:

$\phi(t,x_0) = x_0 + \int_{0}^{t} f(s,\phi(s,x_0)) ds \ (1)$

where $\phi(t,x_0)$ is a function: $\mathbb{R}  \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I'm trying to differentiate  equation of this function both sides  with respect to $x_{0}$. In book from this equation comes from the result of this differentiation is:

$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_0} (t,x_0) = 1 + \int_0^{t} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_0} (s, \phi(s,x_0)) \cdot \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_0} (s, x_0)ds$.

I can't understand expression under the integral. In this book it is explained that it is clear from **chain rule**. When I'm trying to apply the chain rule I have expression under integral such as:

$\frac{\partial }{\partial x_0} f(s, \phi(s,x_0)) = \frac{\partial }{\partial \phi(s,x_0) } f(s, \phi(s,x_0)) \cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial x_0} \phi(s,x_0) $

Could someone explain to me why in my expression first I have derivative respect by $\partial \phi(s,x_0)$ and then by $\partial x_0?$ In solution there are in both expressions $\partial x_0$ Why?

Maybe important is here additional information that differentiable function $(1)$ is solution of differential equation:

$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} (t,x_0) = f(t,\phi,x_0))$, where $\phi(0,x_0)=x(0).$

I will be grateful for your help
Best regards